# Can I downgrade from macOS Sierra to Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6)?

Tags: macos

I have a 2016 MacBook.

First, OS X El Capitan was installed. Now, I've installed Sierra.

Can I downgrade to Snow Leopard?
If I can, is USB method okay?

Comment: You can not install Mac OS X Snow Leopard on a 2016 MacBook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot downgrade the 2016 MacBook Retina to OS X Snow Leopard.

Apple does not support running OS version older than the one shipped with the hardware. Refer to the article [Use the Mac operating system that came with your Mac, or a compatible newer version](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201686):

> Your Mac is designed to work only with compatible macOS versions and builds. If you try to use an incompatible version or build, your Mac might behave unexpectedly.
>
> Avoid using a version of the Mac operating system that is older than what came with your Mac.